# Absolute difference EmguCv

Tags: emgucv

i've recently switched to Emgu CV from OpenCv.. in opencv, i calculated absolute difference using `cvAbsDiff(Frame1,Frame2,foreground);`
and i could check the value of frame difference as: `if(cvNorm(frame2,frame1) > xyz){ ... }`
and here in Emgu cv, i've calculated as: `Difference = Previous_Frame.AbsDiff(Frame);`
as explained [Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/CompareImages_-_Difference) the type of Difference is Image .. i want to know, how can i get the value (double) of difference?? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify your question a little bit more?

But using CvInvoke, you can do:

```
CvInvoke.cvAbsDiff(frame1, frame2, foreground);
double valueInDouble = CvInvoke.cvNorm(frame1, frame2, NORM_TYPE.CV_DIFF, IntPtr.Zero);

if (valueInDouble < xyz){}
```

Mask is an optional parameter(set to NULL in OpenCV documentation), so you can set it to IntPtr.Zero

Comment: Thanks Oliver :) .. i've tried this, but i'm stuck in setting up the value of mask.. what value should i provie it to obtain normal difference value.. cz it's IntPtr type.. should i give it the copy of second frame?

Comment: i have read [http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/43dce521-0a5c-44af-4160-9b3f986c5518.htm] but i really could not understand the use of the "mask" thing here.. :( i'm stuck .. Thanks in advance :)